# How does the createSpy work in Angular + Jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, jasmine, karma-runner

I made a simple demo of a factory and I am trying to test this using **jasmine**. I am able to run the test but I am using the **spyOn** method. I would rather use **jasmine.createSpy** or **jasmine.createSpyObj** to do the same test. Could someone help me to refactor my code so that uses these methods instead in my example?

http://plnkr.co/edit/zdfYdtWbnQz22nEbl6V8?p=preview

```
describe('value check',function(){
  var $scope,
  ctrl,
  fac;
  beforeEach(function(){
    module('app');

  });

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,$controller,appfactory) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();  
     ctrl = $controller('cntrl', {$scope: $scope});
     fac=appfactory;
     spyOn(fac, 'setValue');
     fac.setValue('test abc');
}));


  it('test true value',function(){
    expect(true).toBeTruthy()
  })

   it('check message value',function(){
    expect($scope.message).toEqual(fac.getValue())
  })

   it("tracks that the spy was called", function() {
    expect(fac.setValue).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it("tracks all the arguments of its calls", function() {
    expect(fac.setValue).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test abc');
  });
})
```

update

```
angular.module('app',[]).factory('appfactory',function(){
  var data;
  var obj={};
  obj.getValue=getValue;
  obj.setValue=setValue;

  return obj;

  function getValue(){
   return data; 
  }

  function setValue(datavalue){
    data=datavalue;
  }

}).controller('cntrl',function($scope,appfactory){
  appfactory.setValue('test abc');
  $scope.message=appfactory.getValue()
})
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Except for the second `it()`, all the other ones don't test any of your code: they just test that Jasmine works as documented.

Comment: I am trying to test my factory ..!! i want to test my factory using spyon  and using jasmine.createspy

Comment: If the goal is to test the service, you don't need to create any controller. Inject the service, call its methods, and check that they do what they're supposed to do. You don't need any spy, unless the service you're testing depends on other services, that you want to mock/spy.

Comment: so if you have same service ..how you will test application

Comment: @JBNizet please suggest the solution

Comment: You haven't posted your service. I don't know which methods it has, and what they're supposed to do. Also, you should try testing it first.

Comment: please sea my plunker..there is service in my plunker

Comment: please see update..!!

Comment: The code should be **in the question itself**. And your updated attempt at testing it should be as well. But I confirm: there is zero need to use spies to test such a service. All you need to test is that when you call getValue() after calling setValue(), you get back the expected value. Spies are used to mock **dependencies** of the component under test.

Comment: could you please give plunker...

Comment: Mean how to how if you have this service or factory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, you have absolutely no need for spies to test such a service. If you had to write the documentation for your service: you would say:

> `setValue()` allows storing a value. This value can then be retrieved by calling `getValue()`.

And that's what you should test:

```
describe('appfactory service',function(){
  var appfactory;

  beforeEach(module('app'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_appfactory_) {
    appfactory = _appfactory_;
  }));

  it('should store a value and give it back',function() {
    var value = 'foo';
    appfactory.setValue(value);
    expect(appfactory.getValue()).toBe(value);
  });
});
```

Also, your service is not a factory. A factory is an object that is used to create things. Your service doesn't create anything. It is registered in the angular module using a factory function. But the service itself is not a factory.

Answer (score 2):

I have changed your [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/p24cFRs4eFMcIVY6pvzn?p=preview):

```
 spy = jasmine.createSpy('spy');

 fac.setValue = spy;
```

**Edit**

> In Jasmine, mocks are referred to as spies. There are two ways to
>   create a spy in Jasmine: spyOn() can only be used when the method
>   already exists on the object, whereas jasmine.createSpy() will return
>   a brand new function.

Found the information [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/spy-on-javascript-methods-using-the-jasmine-testing-framework.html#fbid=AttCF-sIsGm). The link has a lot more information about creating spies.

Comment: what you did ...could you explain more

Comment: I simply create a spy by using: jasmine.createSpy. And replaced the function 'setValue' with this spy. I am not a 100% sure, but I believe Jasmine does something very similar when using the 'spyOn' method.