# How to unit test a function in a component that calls method to parent component

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

Hello stackoverflow community.

I am working on an Angular project (1.5.6), using a component structure and currently writing some unit tests. I am still learning a lot about unit tests – especially in relation with Angular – and was hoping I can ask you for help for the following issue:

I try to test a component, that receives a callback method from it's parent component. I am trying to mock the method `foo` (see below the code example). And *unfortunately* does this method call the parent controller.

So when I try to test it, it complains, that the method is undefined. Then I thought I could mock it with spyOn, but then I get the error `Error: <spyOn> : foobar() method does not exist`

So I think I am unable to mock that method.

**Module:**

```
angular.module("myApp")
.component("sample", {
    "templateUrl": "components/sample/sample.html",
    "controller": "SampleController",
    "controllerAs": "sampleCtrl",
    "bindings": {
        "config": "<",
        "foobar": "&"
    }
})
.controller("SampleController",
           ["$scope",
    function($scope) {
        this.isActive = true;

        this.foo = function() {
             // do stuff
             this.isActive = false;

             // also do
             this.foobar();
        };
    }
);
```

**Unit Test**

```
describe("Component: SampleComponent", function() {

    beforeEach(module("myApp"));

    var sampleComponent, scope, $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(inject(function($componentController, $rootScope, _$httpBackend_) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        sampleComponent = $componentController("sample", {
            "$scope": scope
        }); 
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    }));

    it("should do set isActive to false on 'foo' and call method...", function() {
        spyOn(sampleComponent, "foobar")

        expect(sampleComponent.isActive).toBe(true);
        expect(sampleComponent).toBe("");
        expect(sampleComponent.foobar).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

        sampleComponent.foo();

        expect(sampleComponent.foobar).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(sampleComponent.foobar.calls.count()).toBe(1);
        expect(sampleComponent.isActive).toBe(false);
    });
});
```

I hope I didn't add any bugs to this, but this above is *approximately* what I am trying to do. Any suggestions are welcome and if the approach is wrong or more information needed, please let me know!

Comment: `$componentController` is for testing component controller only. So you have to assign a stub to `foobar` property.

Comment: I just thought this could work, because `foobar` gets assigned to the controllers' scope `this.foobar()`. @estus what do you mean with a stub? A method?

Comment: A stub is an empty spy, like `sampleComponent.foobar = jasmine.createSpy()`. $componentController is a wrapper for $controller. It just creates a controller from defined component controller and ignores everything else. To test a component entirely with bindings it should be compiled with `$compile` and so on, it doesn't differ from directives in this case.

Comment: @estus That worked for me! I'll add my solution to my post, but feel free to write that as an answer and I'll select it as a the answer.

Comment: @skofgar You should post the solution as an answer. I think it would help others, they might miss it at a glance.

Comment: @Anthony done. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the help from @estus (see comments in question) - I learned that I can use createSpy to resolve this issue.

```
    it("should do set isActive to false on 'foo' and call method...", function() {
        sampleComponent.foobar = jasmine.createSpy();

        expect(sampleComponent.isActive).toBe(true);
        expect(sampleComponent).toBe("");
        expect(sampleComponent.foobar).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

        sampleComponent.foo();

        expect(sampleComponent.foobar).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(sampleComponent.foobar.calls.count()).toBe(1);
        expect(sampleComponent.isActive).toBe(false);
    });
```

Some additional sources I used were:

- http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/03/introduction-to-unit-test-spies/
- [How does the createSpy work in Angular + Jasmine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556288/how-does-the-createspy-work-in-angular-jasmine)